# I cant ssh into intel content access point from macbook terminal

Tags: ssh, shell

I am trying to ssh into the [intel content access point](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/education/solutions/content-access-point.html) with ubuntu 12.4 installed on it from my macbook air, but i get the following errors:

> ssh: connect to host 192.168.88.1:22 port 22: Operation timed out

Even when i try with this server address: `root@WRTD-303N-Server` I get

> ssh: connect to host wrtd-303n-server port 22: Operation timed out

port 22 is open on the router.

how do i go about this.

Answer (score 0):

There's no mention of SSH in the User Guide. Even though it may run Ubuntu 12, that does not mean that all services are available and the product is likely locked down to prevent non-authorized uses of the product.

You can connect via a web browser though.

This is from page 12 of [Intel Content Access Point](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/education/solutions/ap/sb/pdf/Intel-Education-CAP_uman_331819-001EN.pdf):

**2.7 Log on as admin for the first time**

Wirelessly connect to the device using its default SSID.

The default SSID is WRTD-303N_xxxxxx, where “xxxxxx” is the last six digits of the Wi-Fi MAC address (WFM), which is printed on the bottom of the device.

For example, for a device with a WFM of F835DD85457A, the wireless SSID is
WRTD-303N_85457A.

- Launch a browser and go to http://my.admin (or http://192.168.88.1:8080).
- Enter username `admin` and password `admin` .
- Change the admin default password when prompted.

[image: page 12]

Answer (score -2):

Just try to connect with the user cap

run command: ssh cap@192.168.88.1 
password: 123lkj *(default password)*

Comment: This seems to work to allow me to access the CAP via SSH, however, the user is locked down. Any idea what the root user password is?